# Can't send email through cakephp

Tags: email, cakephp

I need a hand here.

I'm migrating a CakePHP app, and before this we can't send e-mails.

I've facing this log:

```
2017-09-06 11:28:19 Error: [SocketException] Connection refused
Request URL: /admin/settings/mail_test
Stack Trace:
#0 lib/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php(154): CakeSocket->connect()
#1 lib/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php(95): SmtpTransport->_connect()
#2 lib/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php(1161): SmtpTransport->send(Object(CakeEmail))
#3 app/Controller/SettingsController.php(38): CakeEmail->send()
#4 [internal function]: SettingsController->admin_mail_test()
#5 lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(490): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(SettingsController), Array)
#6 lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(193): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#7 lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(167): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(SettingsController), Object(CakeRequest))
#8 app/webroot/index.php(108): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#9 {main}
```

Edit: I've found the gap and solve this issue. 1. My hosting don't allow to use 25 port to send e-mails. 2. After change to Office 365 on por 587, the Exchange only Works with TLS/STARTTLS, we need to configure this on "SmtpTransport.php" file.

Thanks for viewers.

Comment: Please post code and email config file, you are using to send email.